# Symfony 1.4 - Don't save a blank password on a executeUpdate action

Tags: php, symfony1, passwords, symfony-1.4

I have a form to edit a UserProfile which is stored in mysql db. Which includes the following custom configuration:

```
public function configure()
  {
    $this->widgetSchema['password']=new sfWidgetFormInputPassword();
    $this->validatorSchema['password']->setOption('required', false); // you don't need to specify a new password if you are editing a user.
  }
```

When the user tries to save the executeUpdate method is called to commit the changes. 
If the password is left blank, the password field is set to '', but I want it to retain the old password instead of overwriting it.

What is the best (/most in the symfony ethos) way of doing this?  My solution was to override the setter method on the model (which i had done anyway for password encryption), and ignore blank values.

```
public function setPassword( $password )
{
  if ($password=='') return false; // if password is blank don't save it.
  return $this->_set('password', UserProfile ::encryptPassword( $password ));
}
```

It seems to work fine like this, but is there a better way?

If you're wondering I cannot use sfDoctrineGuard for this project as I am dealing with a legacy database, and cannot change the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks fine to me:

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
  if (!$password) return false;
  return $this->_set('password', UserProfile::encryptPassword($password));
}
```

I've got a few forms where I need to update sfGuardUser password along with other form fields that relate to different models, and I've ended up with something like this:

```
$id = // sfGuardUser primary key
$values['password'] = // the form post value returned

if ($values['password']) {
  $user = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->find($id);
  $user->setPassword($values['password']);
  $user->save();
}
```

... saves a value if a value was posted in the form.

Comment: I was thinking there might be something that could be done with post validators.

Comment: Yes, there probably is, but it's just a question of how much time you want to spend on something like this. I would go with your current working solution.